# @import "compass" breaking in asset pipeline rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I have an application.sass inside app/assets/stylesheets and it has in it:

```
@import "compass"
```

When I attempt to launch my development webserver, I get:

```
Error compiling CSS Asset
Sass::SyntaxError:  File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
```

I am using compass-rails-1.0.0.rc.2 with compass-0.12.rc.1

Comment: Have you created a compass project inside `app/assets/stylesheets`? http://compass-style.org/install/

Comment: I found this problem a few times when the rails server didn't shut down properly and was continuing to run in the background. Have you checked to see if there is a phantom sever running?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't your problem, but I just ran across the same error message and spent WAY too long trying different versions of compass/compass-rails, thinking it wasn't my fault.

The problem turned out to be that my **application.css** file wasn't getting run through the sass preprocessor.  So I renamed it to **application.css.scss** and bang!  Yours is named .sass, you could check by renaming it to .css.sass, or .css.scss (just to test) and see if you get different results.

Answer (score 1):

Are you upgrading from a pre-asset pipeline version of Rails (e.g. 3.0)? Please make sure that you are requiring the *assets* group when initializing bundler in your application.rb.

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Otherwise, for compass to work in development, compass-rails and sass-rails must be outside of the *assets* group in your Gemfile.